# Найти одно из слов в тексте (точное совпадение)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, posix

Есть строка:

> "что-то кто-то"

Нужно найти - есть ли в ней точное совпадение одного из слов.
Искать "что" и "кто".

Те чтобы *"что-то"* не совпадало с *"что"*, так же как и *"кто-то"* с *"кто"*.

Делаю так:

```
.*(\bчто\s|\bкто\s).*
```

В итоге получается. 
Но может так случиться что в искомой строке *"что"* - может поменяться на *"что-то"*.Так же с *"кто"*.

Тестю так:

```
1) .*(\bчто-то\s|\bкто\s).*.  - работает
2) .*(\bчто\s|\bкто-то\s).*.  - нет
```

Понятно почему оно не работает. Флаг \s - это символ - пробел||tab||пренос строки. А в тексте после "кто-то" нет никаких символов - это конец строки.

Как сделать так - чтобы в любом случае отрабатывало ? Нужно использовать одинаковый набор спец символов. Те понятно что решение:

```
.*(\bчто\s|\bкто\Z).*
```

отработает, но нужно чтобы была комбинация [\s или \Z] . Я пытаюсь делать так:

```
.*(\bчто[\s|\Z]|\bкто[\s|\Z]).*
```

не хочет отрабатывать. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать правильно.

Comment: Используйте `(^| )[чк]то($| )`. Почему вы добавили тег POSIX?

Comment: Где используется выражение? Приведите, пожалуйста, код.

Comment: .*(\bчто($| )|\bкто($| )).* - получилось так ) Виктор, спасибо большое! Интересно можно ли чем-то более лаконичным заменить ($| ) ?   (^| ) - поменял на \b

Comment: Если вы используете POSIX, то нет. В других случаях, лучше `(?!\S)`

Comment: а вот ж  .*(\bчто(\Z|\s)|\bкто(\Z|\s)).*   ˆ_ˆ

Comment: Вы используете Java? Зачем `\Z`? Зачем `.*`? `\Z` несовместим с POSIX BRE/ERE.

Comment: PHP, а как правильно?

Comment: * потестил - отрабатывает. только нюанс что добавило пустых элементов в массив из-за того что (\Z|\s) в скобках - поэтому взяло в результат. Если бы еще без этого )

Comment: `.*\b([кч]то)(?:\Z|\s).*` - подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```
\b([кч]то)(\Z|\s)
```

Если необходимо совпадение целой строки, добавьте `.*` по краям:

```
.*\b([кч]то)(\Z|\s).*
```

Если у вас несколько альтернатив, используйте подмаску следующим образом:

```
.*\b(кто|что|ещё)(\Z|\s).*
```

Если можно использовать незахватывающие подмаски, используйте

```
.*\b(кто|что|ещё)(?:\Z|\s).*
```

Однако POSIX их обычно не поддерживает (так же как и `\Z` впрочем).

Comment: А разве `\b` работает адекватно с кириллицей? Сталкивался что с кириллицей не работала граница слова.

Comment: @PotroNik Тут не совсем ясно, что это за "POSIX". Если вы работаете только с JS, то понятно, почему у вас `\b` вызывает подозрения. Только в других языках `\b` с кириллицей дружит очень даже хорошо. [PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/zYW9T9/1), [Python](https://regex101.com/r/zYW9T9/2), [Onigmo (Ruby)](https://rubular.com/r/2A1ylAcmxB1cOr), [.NET](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%5cb&i=%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9+%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3)...